# How can I get a Vertical Scroll in my web-page?

Tags: css, scrollbar, frontend

I did a web-page: [my-web-page](http://wyzc.de)
But there is no Vertical Scroll bar when reducing browser window.
How can I get the Vertical Scroll?

My style.css File as follow:

[a busy cat http://www.cde-express.com/wangying/css.jpg](http://www.cde-express.com/wangying/css.jpg)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have overflow set to hidden as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbar is hidden because you're explicitly hiding it.

If you get rid of the part `overflow: hidden` on line 24, you should see your scrollbar back. Your line 24 should look like:

```
body{ margin: 0;padding: 25px 0px 0px 30px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this may help you !!
Simply add this line to your DIV with css of "main class"

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Thats it :) your left pan will be scrollable.
If want some stylish Scroll Bar, then add these lines in the start of your CSS File.

```
/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px greenyellow; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: orange; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px blueviolet; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
        background: yellow; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For having only vertical scroll we can use overflow-y property in css.. It restricts it to vertical scroll alone.